# How to strech(scale) mesh on the world axis

Tags: javascript, three.js

There is an online 3d editor where you can edit individual meshes (move, scale, rotate). Ability to edit meshes implemented using custom transform controls which based on threejs's TransformControls code. This is fragment from mousemove event:

```
var intersect = intersectObjects(pointer, [xzPlane]); // intersect mouse's pointer with horizontal plane

var point = new THREE.Vector3();
point.copy(intersect.point);
point.sub(offset); // coords from mousedown event (from start stretching)

// some code for 'scale' value calculating base on 'point' variable
// var scale = ...;
//

 mesh.scale.x = scale;
```

This code works well if the mesh does not rotate.

Requires scaling always happened to the world coordinate system. This is programming question

For example, from this:

[image: rotated, but not scaled]

To this:

[image: rotated, then scaled]

P.S. I think that custom mesh matrix must be created, but I have very little experience with matrices

Thanks!

Comment: Post some code. We can't give an answer unless we have some context? If this is a three.js question remove the `WebGL` tag.

Comment: I removed the `WebGL` tag. This question in Three.js context. I do editor, in which one of the functions - stretching meshes on one or two global axis. The three.js has a function of stretching(scaling), but only on local axes.

Comment: 1. You cannot apply a matrix transformation on the geometry within the editor, but you can with your own code. 2. Is this an editor question or a programming question? 3. Show some context to your question with more code. Does your object already have a rotation that is non-zero?

Comment: I adjusted the wording of the question. Thank you for your attention to this matter

Comment: Here. Start with [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tm7Ab/). Edit it, and ask a specific question so we understand what your requirements are.

Comment: I edit jsfiddle. I had asked this question on github there are screenshots to help you understand the problem https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/4655 (unfortunately I can not add pictures because I have a small rating on Stack Overflow)

Comment: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Tm7Ab/1/) edited jsfiddle

Comment: See if the approach in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tm7Ab/5/) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes! this is what I wanted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting the rotation, like so:

```
mesh.rotation.set( Math.PI/4, 0, 0 );
```

apply the identical rotation to the geometry, instead:

```
var euler = new THREE.Euler( Math.PI / 4, 0, 0 );
mesh.geometry.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationFromEuler( euler ) );
```

Now, you can set the scale and get the result you want.

```
mesh.scale.z = 2;
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Tm7Ab/5/

three.js r.67

Comment: How do I do this without modifying the geometry? It's easy to scale objects, but they are scaled locally. I need to apply a world vector to the rotated object to scale it in world space without modifying the object and without adding it to any other parent objects. Also, I'm using r71 because I can't update to new versions yet.

Comment: I thought about modifying the scale vector to make it local to the object, but I haven't been able to make it work.

Comment: This doesn't work for example:  
     localVector.copy(vector);
     localVector.applyQuaternion(instance.quaternion.inverse());
     instance.scale.set(instance.scale.x * localVector.x,instance.scale.y * localVector.y,instance.scale.z * localVector.z);